# TestFlight gives users null app after uninstalling

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad

Some of our users are running into an issue in a beta app of ours. They're attempting to unisntall an app (iOS 9.1, iPad Air) and finding a null app left over after uninstall. From one of the reports:

> I then tried deleting the app through GameCenter.  The GameCenter app
>   asked me if I wanted to uninstall the app as well, and I said yes. 
>   However, I noticed that the app was still present on the home screen,
>   so I deleted it there as well.
>
> Now, TestFlight says “Open”, not “Install”, even though the game is
>   not present on the home screen.

It appears that the deleted app is now a null package on the phone, which doesn't show up on the home screen. They can't install the app again in TestFlight because TestFlight believes it's already installed.

From their more detailed report:

> In Settings->General->Storage->Manage Storage, I found a 67.5 MB
>   “null” app.  I deleted it, and it goes away - but if I go back into
>   the Manage Storage page, it reappears.  I tried hard-resetting, but no
>   difference.
>
> In iExplore, I can see that com.XXXXXXXX.XXXXXXX is present, but I
>   can’t interact with it.
>
> In XCode, I see it on the list of installed apps (under
>   Window->Devices, with latest OSX and XCode).  When I delete it, it
>   goes away and immediately returns.  In the log, I see that the
>   uninstall is requested, and then this error: [MIContainer
>   allContainersForIdentifier:options:error:]: 348: No bundle container
>   found for identifier com.XXXXXXXX.XXXXXXX (this was the app ID) and
>   then a warning that no uninstall occurred.

I'm looking for feedback from other app developers who have run into this issue. How can users remove the app from device, and re-install from TestFlight?

Comment: Hi Alex, have you filed a radar? And if not, can you and post the radar number here?

Comment: Hey there, it's Radar report 23464103.